# Delete all but top 10 for every type Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, .net, entity-framework

Let's say that I have a table like:

```
Id    Name   Category   CreatedDate
1     test   test       10-10-2015
2     test1  test1      10-10-2015
...
```

Now, I would like to delete all rows and leave only the top 10 from all categories (by top 10 I mean the 10 newest according to `createdDate`).

Using raw SQL, it would be like:

```
DELETE FROM [Product]
WHERE id NOT IN
(
    SELECT id FROM
    (
        SELECT id, RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY Category ORDER BY createdDate DESC) num
        FROM [Product]
    ) X
WHERE num <= 10
```

How is this done when using the `DbContext` in Entity Framework?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
// GET all products
var list = ctx.Products.ToList();

// GROUP by category, ORDER by date descending, SKIP 10 rows by category
var groupByListToRemove = list.GroupBy(x => x.Category)
                              .Select(x => x.OrderByDescending(y => y.CreatedDate)
                                            .Skip(10).ToList());

// SELECT all data to remove
var listToRemove = groupByListToRemove.SelectMany(x => x);

// Have fun!
ctx.Products.RemoveRange(listToRemove);
```

Answer (score 0):

Guessing it will take a whil if you have a lot of data but.

```
var oldItems = efContext.Products
.GroupBy(x => x.Category, 
(c,p) => p.OrderByDescending(x => p.createdDate).Skip(10))
.SelectMany(p => p);
efContext.Products.RemoveRange(oldItems);
```

Will do the trick
(Written in notepad)